# Get Preferred Culture Info / Language - C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I am trying to get the users preferred language.  I see all kinds of articles on how to set it, but they assume that the user is telling it which language to select (like in a dropdownlist).

In Firefox under Tools > Options > Content > Languages > Choose  you can select which languages you prefer and choose their order.  I want to be able to access that list, or at least the preferred language in the C# codebehind.  How do I go about this? Is this possible?

Everything I have tried always returns en-US, no matter whats in the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe what your after is this

```
Request.UserLanguages
```

From the documentation

"Gets a sorted string array of client languages preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser sends this in the Accept-Language header field, as [documented by W3c](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). However, I am not sure how to access that from ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim userLocale
userLocale=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")

Dim languages
languages = Split(userLocale, ",", -1)
```